# Creating a login form error message (php,css,html)

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a error message/ trying to make my css box's to turn red when there is no input after the login button is pressed.

[image: my login page]

```
   <?php
    session_start();    //starting the db session



    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "authentication");     // database connection selections, aswell as setting a variable.  db = database

    if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);       // this is giving the login button a command, defining that the variables $password and username are the box contents
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

        $password = md5($password); //sha256 is a type of hash, making the password more secure
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);



        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Succesfully logged in";  //the, if login details are correct you will re-directed to the home.php page, else message: unsuccessfully logged in
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;                      //validation if user name = db username
            header("location: home.php");  //location
        }else{
            // turn the box's RED hear as error ???
        }
    }



?>
```

This is part of my php for the login page, as you can see I wanted to make the box's red after the else.

My css for this page so far is ..

```
}

body {
    background-color: #FF9615;
}



.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

The username, password login button are all in the login-page class and the form class.
Any advice of how I would go about doing what I want. I have tried to look for a good few hours but can find nothing to help me in the way I want.

Any help is appreciated.
- Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to do this via php you could have your post back add a class to your form inputs, something like:

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();    //starting the db session

$error = ""; //Set the class to empty on page load

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "authentication");     // database 
connection selections, aswell as setting a variable.  db = database

if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);       // this is giving the login button a command, defining that the variables $password and username are the box contents
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    $password = md5($password); //sha256 is a type of hash, making the password more secure
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if ($username == "")
    {
        $error = "no-content-error";
    } 
    ///The rest of your php code
?>
```

CSS

```
.no-content-error
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="<?php echo $error; ?>"/>
    ///The rest of your html
</form>
```

Just use the html for the forms exactly the same way. Add another error for any other empty inputs the same way.

Comment: I have attempted to do what you have noted above but it still does not seem to be changing the box to a red border. As shown: http://prntscr.com/l8nnt8 and the html is http://prntscr.com/l8nnzm the css just includes what you suggested. Am I doing it all wrong ?

Comment: @Rheina you have a form post nested inside another form post, remove the second (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) from your code.